# ImageMagick works by command line but doesn't work from PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick

I use Windows 7 and Apache server on my personal computer to develop web applications. Today I installed the ImageMagick for Windows and when I try do an operation from command line it works, for example:

```
convert -scale "300x300>" -quality 80 -strip "d:/www/test.jpg" "d:/www/test2.jpg"
```

But the same command run from PHP doesn't work:

```
exec('convert -scale "300x300>" -quality 80 -strip "d:/www/test.jpg" "d:/www/test2.jpg"');
```

Why? Please help me!

Comment: You aren't supplying enough information. Do you get an error message? You can set a variable equal to the exec command to see its output. Having said that, this is likely a path issue. Either the path to convert or to the file isn't correctly specified.

Comment: This looks like a $PATH-issue. What does error.log say?

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Any errors?

I successfully use imagemagick on Windows 7 from PHP, by using the absolute path to imagemagick.

```
exec('C:\imagemagick\convert -scale "300x300>" -quality 80 -strip "d:/www/test.jpg" "d:/www/test2.jpg"');
```

Comment: That's it! I just needed to provide absolute path! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

use below form for paths

```
d:\www\test.jpg
d:\www\test2.jpg
```